# What are best practices for independent deployments in microservices architecture?

Tags: deployment, microservices

I have several microservices cooperating with each other which I'd like to deploy independently. What are the prerequisits for such scenario? Or better: what are the best practices?

What I came with so far is:

- contract versioning
- atomated intergration tests
- phased (canary?) deployment scenario to minimize risk
- rollback scenario

Are there any others topics to consider?

Comment: How are they cooperating?  Pubsub messaging, REST/gRPC/etc. requests?

Comment: @LeviRamsey it's REST, does it matter?